# Time axis based on the last 24 hours

Tags: matlab

I am trying to find a way to make my axis go from a certain time to the same time 24h later.
What I mean is that I am taking measurements for the last 24 hours and I want my axis to be limited and have certain ticks.

More specifically, I get measurements which start at 10am on the 1st of Nov and it finishes at 10am on the 2nd of Nov.
And i want my axis to go from 10 to 24 / 00 to 10 with 1h steps (ticks).

Any suggestions on how to do that are more than welcome.

Thanks a lot for your time.

Comment: `xlim([ValueOfYourTimeSignalStart ValueOfYourTimeSignalEnd])` limits your axis.
`set(gca,'XTicks', ValueOfYourTimeSignalStart:(ValueOfYourTimeSignalStart-ValueOfYourTimeSignalEnd)/24:ValueOfYourTimeSignalEnd)` creates the desired Tíckmarks on the x-axis
`set(gca,'XTickLabel',CellStrings)` add the Labels

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. I forgot to mention that I get the time in this format 
'2016-05-21 04:05:00'
'2016-05-21 04:10:00'
'2016-05-21 04:15:00'
and I didn't even plot against the time. All I need is the axis to be in that format.

So I am essentially plotting 1 point every 5 mins, but I want the axis and the ticks to be labeled differently.

I am currently using datenum, but that gives me totally different numbers on the axis.

Comment: `datestr` with a proper string formatting should do the job to derive the tick labels from the tick values. Alternatively, you can easily create your own cell of strings featuring the desired time information by hand.

Comment: Finally made it! Thanks a lot Chris! I didn't really need datestr in the end. Datenum and datevec did it for me. Used datenum for the plot and tick and datevec for the tick labels.

`plot(timefin(l-288:l),y(l-288:l,26),'r','Linewidth', 2)`

  `set(gca,'xtick',[timefin(l-288):(3/24):timefin(l)])`

  `xlim([timefin(l-288) timefin(l)])`

 `set(gca,'xticklabel',{hour(l-288) hour(l-252) hour(l-216) hour(l-180) hour(l-144) hour(l-108) hour(l-72) hour(l-36) hour(l)})`